# Ajuda em Formato de Números modo simples

Tags: javascript, react-native

Acho que minha pergunta é boba, mais eu nunca cheguei a fazer esse teste. tem alguma forma de recuperar o valor assim 10.90 com o zero sem usar função ou replace, já tentei aqui mais sem sucesso!

```
var total = 10.90;

totalreal = parseInt(total)
totalrealF = parseFloat(total)
totalrealN = Number(total)

document.write(

'R$ ' + totalreal +  '<br>' +
'R$ ' + totalrealF + '<br>' +
'R$ ' + totalrealN + '<br>' +
'R$ ' + total +          '<br>'

);
```

saida

```
R$ 10
R$ 10.9
R$ 10.9
R$ 10.9
```

desejado

```
R$ 10.90
```

Comment: `total.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o precision da para exibir como você deseja só não sei se satisfaz o uso:

> toPrecision

```
var total = 10.90;


totalrealF = parseFloat(total).toPrecision(4)


console.log(totalrealF)
```

> referência : [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp)

Comment: Obrigada! simples!